# Azure DevOps self hosted windows agent to Azure Linux function app deployment

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I am working on  Linux based Azure functions with Python 3.7 and trying to use Azure DevOps. My python project has requirements like psycopg2-binary, cython to name a few of them.

We have been provisioned a self hosted windows agent pool in Azure Devops. I am building a pipeline and my concern is that the deployment won't be successful since the build would happen on the dev agent (on windows) and deployment is on Azure Functions (linux).

Do we need a linux agent in this case?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need a linux agent in this case?

As far as I know, you don't need to use a Linux agent to build the Python project.

You can directly use the python package built by windows agent to deploy to the linux azure function.

When you using tasks(e.g. [Azure Functions
task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-function-app?view=azure-devops) or [Azure App Service deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops)) to deploy the package to Azure Function app, it will directly publish the packages and the Configuration to Azure Function app.

The prerequisite is that the deployed package meets the requirements of the task: the package is a **zip or war** file. So you need to use the **Archive files task** to pack the published files.

[image]

If the configuration of the python project can be run in the linux system, the same configuration can also be run in the linux Function App.

For more details about deploy a Python project to Azure, you could refer to this doc: [deploy a Python web app to Azure App Service on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops)